# You don't have permission to access this resource. Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered

Tags: javascript, php

I have a website that I built on core PHP.it works perfectly fine in localhost. Now I uploaded on host break server in the public_html folder. when I try to upload an image it gives an error "You don't have permission to access this resource.  Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request".Please help me with this. This does not give on a specific section. All the modules which have an option to upload an image give the same error.
**front end code of form**

```
<form class="col-md-6" style="margin-left: 25%;background-color: #0D3349;color: white" action="addclientbackened.php" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <h1 style="text-align: center;color: white">Add images for Gallery</h1>
            <br>
            <br>
            <hr>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter Category name" name="name" required>
            </div>


            <hr>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="fpimage">Font Page image</label>
                <input type="file" id="fpimage" name="fpimage" required>
                <hr>

            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="save" value="save" style="font-size: 20px;margin-left: 42%">
            <br>
        </form>
```

**backened code of form**

```
<?php

    include "db.php";

    $fpimage= $_FILES['fpimage']['name'];
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fpimage"]["tmp_name"]);
    if ($check !== false) {

        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
        throw new Exception("file is not and image");
    }

    $target_dir = "client/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fpimage"]["name"]);
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));


    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
    }


    else {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fpimage']['tmp_name'], $target_dir . $fpimage);
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $sql = "insert into hclients(name,image) values('".$name."','".$fpimage."')";
        $result = mysqli_query($connn, $sql);
        if ($result) {
//          header('location:addclient.php');
            echo '<script language="javascript">';
            echo 'alert("Client stored successfuly")';
            echo '</script>';
            echo "<script> location='addclient.php' </script>";
        } else {
            echo mysqli_error($connn);

        }

    }


?>
```

Here is the image of error

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely caused by your web server, or path/file permissions.
For instance, in Linux, your path is not writable for user www-data or anyone the web server run-as.

In Apache web server, the configuration file or the *htaccess* file made the directory or file not readable, writable, etc.

To solve your problem, it's more required to provide the system and web server information, such as:

- Operating System?
- Web server?
- Web server configuration?
- Directory permissions

Hope this information helps.

Comment: I uploaded my website on the host break server. and I don't have .htaccess file

Comment: You can try to write file to the same directory in PHP, such as using function file_put_contents($path,$content); to see if there is permission issue in PHP script to divide the problem.